# Magento doesn't display product images more than 1 MB

Tags: image, cache, upload

Product image is uploaded succesfully in admin backend, but it doesn't display on frontend product page (404 error).

The image backend url:
`/media/catalog/product/5/0/50_2_1_4.jpg`

Frontend url: `/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/0/50_2_1_4.jpg` and it doesn't exist on ftp.

If file size less than **1 MB**, frontend image uploads ok.

I checked chmod permissions for `media` and all subfolders - 777.

My server has `curl`; `image gd - enabled`; `file_uploads - on`; `upload_max_filesize - 12M`; `post_max_size - 20M`; `max_file_uploads - 20`; `upload_tmp_dir - no value`;

I enabled/disabled/updated/flushed magento cache but nothing solved the issue.

Is it possible to remove this limit and how can I do it?

Hope for your help and thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Consult your error log for errors, I anticipate you are seeing a memory limit exception.

You will likely need to increase the memory_limit attribute in php.ini from the 1M it appears to be set to, to something more useful.

Mine is set to 512M at this time.

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

However, you may find your host has imposed limits, or hiding somewhere in your code is a

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1M');
```

Which is overriding the php.ini set value.

In some cases this value can also be set in .htaccess so check there also.